# Set State in input type without callback function

Tags: reactjs, setstate, input-field

I am trying to set state in input field itself. it is giving me 
  `[object object]`, when I type in some value. Following is the code:

```
<input
  type="text"
  name='name'
  value={this.state.name}
  onChange= {(name) => this.setState({ name })}
/>
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: The name that you passed is actually event object. It is not the `name` on your input element.

Answer (score 4):

You are probably passing whole event object, instead of just value of target. Try this:

```
onChange={e => setState({name: e.target.value})}
```

For better understand read this: https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html

Answer (score 2):

Well when the `onChange` event is triggered on an input tag, an [Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) object is being passed to the callback function. So to get the value of what the user is typing, you should change that to

```
onChange={(event) => this.setState({name: event.target.value})}
```